# Video card not found on an HP Mini 210-2000ew

Tags: drivers, hp

I've installed newest Ubuntu on my HP Mini 210-2000ew and I have problems with drivers. My system works very slow, because it doesn't even recognize my graphic card. Could someone give me links for websites where I can get them? I found some in Intel website, but they give me link for another site, in which I have no idea what should I download. Please help me with those drivers.

Comment: Well you already have the drivers installed, Ubuntu installs them by default it can be slow because something else makes it so, what are the netbook specs? oh an don't use Unity 3D (log in session is Ubuntu) use Unity 2D.

Comment: This is likely a **Cedarview** issue. What is the CPU and graphics-chip for this model?